# How to create array of type with having list of object similar type in C#

Tags: c#

We have third party class which only accepts arrays of object.

Third Party class :

```
public class Test
{
    public class Input
    {

        public int testVar { get; set; }
        public int testVar2 { get; set; }
    }
    //some methods

    public static List<someType> Convert(Input[] data)
    {
        //execute some steps 
    }
}
```

in DB, we have the data column which we are interested and it has thousand of records.

```
Id        data

    1   new Test.Input{ testVar=12,testVar=19}
    2   new Test.Input{ testVar=16,testVar=12}
    3   new Test.Input{ testVar=26,testVar=11}
    -
```

i am trying to create a class and invoke Convert method of Test class by providing array of Input type object .

```
public class ImplementTest
{
    public void CallConvert()
    {
        // get the data from DB in list
        List<object> Input = new List<object>();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {

                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = "dbo.ReadAll_Input";

                con.Open();

                using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        Input.Add(dr["data"]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //convert list object to input type object  
        var inputs = new Test.Input[]
        {
           //how to pass Input list efficiently
        };

        var output = Test.Convert(inputs).ToArray();
    }
}
```

can anyone help me on passing Input list object to Create array of object efficiently please?

Thanks!

Comment: why do you use `List<object> Input ` and not `List<Test.Input> Input ` ?

Comment: @Tigran , because it may contain null values , so i need to filter them out and also data which i am fetching from DB contains Input Type create object structure. can we do that way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Mapper method:

```
public Input MapRow(IDataRecord row)
{
    return new Input
    {
        Name = row["Name"].ToString(),
        Number = int.Parse(row["Number"].ToString())
    };
}
```

And use it like this:

```
public void CallConvert()
{
    // get the data from DB in list
    List<Input> inputs = new List<Input>();

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "dbo.ReadAll_Input";

            con.Open();

            using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    inputs.Add(MapRow(dr));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    var output=Test.Convert(inputs.ToArray());
}
```

And to make it work, your stored procedure should return a table of inputs with, in this case, two columns `(Name, Number)`

Comment: Actually the data we are getting from DB is already in object initialisation structure.i think this won't work..will check.Thanks!

Comment: That's a bummer! could you post the data structure resulting from the SP to see how it looks like? I'm not sure what you mean by `object initialisation structure`.

Comment: I have posted it in question.data row we have like this: "new Test.Input{ testVar=12,testVar=19}". and we have 100 thousands record.